# Getting an error "the input file is same as the output file

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, gcc

I am very new to C programming and I just installed mingw and started using vs code. I have installed all teh extension required in the VS code and have selected the default builder as gcc in the vs code.

here is the source code I am trying to run
main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int age;
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    printf("Whats your age?: ");
    scanf("%i", &age);
    printf("You are %i years old", age);
    return 0;
    
}
```

here is the tasks.json which I created:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

But on building the file (ctrl+shift+B), I get the following error:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file <

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -g -fdiagnostics-color=always C:\Users\user name\Desktop\username's folder laptop\College CS\C programming\main.c -o C:\Users\user name\Desktop\username's folder laptop\College CS\C programming\main.exe
gcc.exe: fatal error: input file 'C:\Users\user' is the same as output file
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

I have tried deleting and recreating the .c file.

It works fine when I type the following command in the cmd manually after going into that folder:
`gcc main.c -o main.exe`
So, the gcc works fine but for some reason when I mention the whole path, it goes haywire.

Please help me out as I couldn't find any solutions for this error and sorry of this doubt is a silly one.

I was expecting the build to be successful in VS code but it showed a fatal error even though the VS code is open in that particular folder.

Comment: Your path `C:\Users\user name\Desktop\username's folder laptop\College CS\C programming\main.c` has spaces in it; it will need to be quoted in the gcc command line.  Same for every other argument that is related to `${fileDirname}`

Comment: Note that the error message gives a very strong clue to what's going on, as it thinks the input file is named just `C:\Users\user`

Comment: so it should be like "C:\Users\user name\Desktop\username's folder laptop\College CS\C programming\main.c "?

Comment: It looks like it, but I never thought that double quotes were accepted in cmd

Comment: Yes, if there are quotes around the multi-word filename, gcc will run correctly (or at least, without this error)

Comment: On Windows it isn't "cmd" that receives the quotes, but the program you are running.  Unlike Unix/Linux where an array of arguments is passed to the program, Windows passes a single "command line" string and the program breaks it apart (usually with the help of a standard function, but individual programs can choose to do trickier things)

Comment: Ok, I think I get your point. So for example, if we take the cmd line which I have mentioned in the question, the GCC is the program and the "main.c -o main.exe" is the string of arrays which is broken down using the standard functions of the gcc. Correct?

Comment: Now that I have added the quotes it is working out fine for now. Thanks for pointing that out, or else I might have been stuck on that blunder cluelessly.

Comment: Pretty much, although like I said gcc just receives one string not an array of strings, and it has to break that one string apart into an array or list of options, filenames, etc.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for helping me out and giving a good insight into gcc. Will be helpful while I am programming in C. Thank you very much.